# Unable to get network info for ChromeApp with ARC

Tags: android, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-arc

I'm trying to port my Android application to Chrome using ARC Welder and am having some trouble getting information about the network. In particular, I'd like to get

- The current IP address
- The IP address of the gateway
- If we're on wireless, the SSID + BSSID of the network, along with whatever other wireless info is available

If some of this info is not available, I'll take ANY info

I've tried several things and nothing works. I've retrieved the WifiManager, retrieved NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(), and even tried InetAddress.getLocalHost(). Nothing works.

I'm starting to feel that this is because the app is being sandboxed and perhaps I need to put something in the manifest. Unfortunately, little documentation exists for this.

Any ideas on how I can get this?

Comment: ARC acts similar to emulator ... so there is no direct connection to internet but rathe some kind of "virtual network card"

Comment: That doesn't sound like good news. I did notice that when I get a WifiManager it seems to have bogus information. Is there anything that can be done about this? Perhaps doing something at the JavaScript level?